# How to check if a datetime is equal to 20:00 *local* time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have a requirement in my application where we have to perform certain activities based on the time (that too local to the client)... For example - if the client is in US and the local time at the client is 20:00 then do something...

So far to simplify we are taking just one timezone for each country.. Any pointers how can I check if the time is 20:00 at the client based on the timezone??

Comment: It sounds like you want to set up a timer that fires at 20:00, rather than explicitly check the time; otherwise you'll have to be checking it continuously, all the time.

Comment: +1 for a suggested timer.  The only thing is, there's a few timers to choose from...

Comment: We already have a scheduled job.. I was looking for the C# code that Jon Skeet has provided..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, you'll want the [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) for the client. Then you can use:

```
DateTimeOffset clientNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                                                    timeZone);

if (clientNow.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.FromHours(20))
{
    // ...
}
```

(Of course, that would only work at the *exact instant* of 20:00. You'll want to adjust it according to your real requirements.)

Answer (score 3):

Use [quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to schedule a job instead. It is very easy to work with an it is very stable as well.

If you need the timezone thing, just trigger the job every hour and fire the activity you want for the clients that apply.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean isDateTimeEqualToTwentyAught() {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that there's a bug, err, feature in DateTime class that allows you to compare values in different timezones completely ignoring said timezones.  Test, test, and retest to make sure it's what you want.